# Retrieving 'App Page' category 'likes' of a user on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, response, facebook-like, facebook-apps

When I use the usual 'like' api call, the response doesn't have any data of category 'App page'. But when i use,  /me/likes/App_Page_id, i get a response if I have liked that app page and get a Null response if I haven't.

Is there any way by which I can retrieve all 'App page' category likes on facebook??

Please do help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) and retrieve all the pages with `type="APP PAGE"` as following

```
select name,page_id,type 
from page 
where page_id in (select page_id from page_fan where uid=me())
and type="APP PAGE"
```

This will give all the `APP PAGES` liked by the user. The prerequisite for this to work is `user_likes` permission.

Comment: FQL is an API in itself similar to Graph API, Could you tell what SDK are you using?

Comment: Thank you Anvesh; that was informative. But still the same problem exists. I don't get any APP PAGE category results. When I add 'and type= "APP PAGE" ' the response is null. When I remove the above mentioned code, I get all other category responses but no APP PAGE category.